# Acces VBA Export 2 tables to one excel with criteria

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've been testing and searching for a couple of weeks and i think its now time after hundreds of tests, to ask help. Here's my situation.

I have two tables in MS Access:

1. `Journal_personeel_verloning` (or `table1`)

   - Table 1 has several employees, let's say: 5 different employees.
   - Table 1 has working time details example: every day working from to hours
2. `Journal_personeel_verloning_2_all` (or `table2`)

   - Table 2 has also several employees, let's say too: 5 different employees.
   - Table 2 has total worked time for that month of each employee

Notes:

- Table 1 and table 2 have exactly the same employees always.
- `Persid` is the fieldname should filter on (both tables has this fieldname)

---

What do I want to achieve: I want to export two tables to one Excel file with following conditions:

- 1 Excel file containing data of 2 tables
- Each `PersID` on seperate sheet/tab
- Each sheet/tab name would be `PersID`

Problem

I wrote a code which works fine with `table1`. When I do the same with `table2`, then it overwrites. So each time I have data of one table instead of data of two table per sheet/tab containing data from total two tables.

I copied the code for `table2`. If I rename the Excel output file, then I get two separate files of course:

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstMgr As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, strTemp As String, strMgr As String
-----------------

Const strFileName As String = "Employee_Verloning"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False


Const strQName As String = "zExportQuery"

Set dbs = CurrentDb
strTemp = dbs.TableDefs(0).Name

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & strTemp & "] WHERE 1=0;"

Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strQName, strSQL)
qdf.Close

strTemp = strQName

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Persid FROM Journal_personeel_verloning;"

Set rstMgr = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)


If rstMgr.EOF = False And rstMgr.BOF = False Then
      rstMgr.MoveFirst
      Do While rstMgr.EOF = False

            strMgr = DLookup("CHAUFFEURR", "Journal_personeel_verloning", _
                  "Persid = " & rstMgr!Persid.value)
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Journal_personeel_verloning WHERE " & _
                  "Persid = " & rstMgr!Persid.value & ";"


            Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs(strTemp)
            qdf.Name = strMgr
            strTemp = qdf.Name
            qdf.SQL = strSQL
            qdf.Close
            Set qdf = Nothing


            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            Transfertype:=acExport, _
            SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            TableName:=strTemp, _
            Filename:="M:\Public\Exports XLS\Personeel\" & strFileName & ".xls", _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:=strMgr

            rstMgr.MoveNext


      Loop


End If


rstMgr.Close
Set rstMgr = Nothing
dbs.QueryDefs.Delete strTemp
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
```

So any help is much appreciate...

Edit:
Let me more clear:

```
Table 1:

ID Persid Chauffeur Proj Starttime Endtime
1  85     John      A    10:00     12:00
2  86     Fred      X    10:00     12:00
3  85     John      A    10:00     12:00
4  86     Fred      A    10:00     12:00

Journal_personeel_verloning_2_all (or table2)

Table 2:
ID Persid Chauffeur Proj Totalworkedtime(decimal)
1  85     John      A    4
2  86     Fred      A    2
3  86     Fred      X    2

Export must look like this:

1 excel file with:
tabname: John

ID Persid Chauffeur Proj Starttime Endtime
1  85     John      A    10:00     12:00
3  85     John      A    10:00     12:00

(1 or 2 empty rows)

ID Persid Chauffeur Proj Totalworkedtime(decimal)
1  85     John      A    4

same excel with second tabname: Fred

ID Persid Chauffeur Proj Starttime Endtime
2  86     Fred      X    10:00     12:00
4  86     Fred      A    10:00     12:00

(1 or 2 empty rows)

ID Persid Chauffeur Proj Totalworkedtime(decimal)
2  86     Fred      A    2
3  86     Fred      X    2
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Hakan. Please, follow [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). From question it isn't clear what did you look for before posting to stackoverflow, why do you think provided code should work and what prevents you from progressing.

Comment: You may have answered your own question: *Table 1 and table 2 have exactly the same employees always*. So, of course the same named tabs would be overwritten with each run of code. Why not join the two tables and then export in each tab?

Comment: Since you already know how to use recordsets, instead of `TransferSpreadsheet`, use `Range.CopyFromRecordSet`. You will be in full control

Comment: @patrickHonorez Thanks for you help. I put the code above from several examples in 1 working code. So im am not so super vba programmer, so if you can more specific maybe with example then i can try to implement according to my situation. thanks in advance

Comment: I once wrote a small function for that. You might get some inspiration from it. https://gist.github.com/PatrickHonorez/432c51c85721592675e2779773b831f2

Comment: OK thanks i would look at that :)

Comment: @patrickHonorez i looked at it. Still not enough inspiration how to arrange 2 table with loop criteria per sheet..

Comment: Still not succeed working code..If someone has a solution?